# Verifying DSA Signature generated by PKCS#11 with OpenSSL

Tags: encryption, dsa, encoding, pkcs#11

I want to sign a SHA-256 hash with DSA using PKCS#11 Java Wrapper for the PKCS#11 API of a hardware security module. For this purpose I selected the Mechanism CKM_DSA, load the corresponding DSA key from the token and have the data (read as byte-array) signed. The key I use for testing has 1024bit length.

Everything seems to work fine: The key is loaded, the Session.sign() yields a byte[] array of length 40. This corresponds to the PKCS#11 Spec, which says:

"*For the purposes of this mechanism, a DSA signature is a 40-byte string, 
corresponding to the concatenation of the DSA values r and s, each represented most significant byte first.*"

Now I want to verify this signature using openSSL, i.e., using

```
openssl dgst -d -sha256 -verify ${PUBLIC_KEY} -signature signature.der <raw input file>
```

This works if I

a) created the signature using OpenSSL

b) created the signature using bouncycastle and encoding the result as ASN1 encoded DER sequence.

Now I want to do the same with the PKCS#11 signature. My question is: how to format this 40 byte array? I tried the following:

```
        //sign data
        byte[] signedData = this.pkcs11Session.sign(dataToSign);
        //convert result
        byte[] r = new byte[20];
        byte[] s = new byte[20];
        System.arraycopy(signedData, 0, r, 0, 20);
        System.arraycopy(signedData, 19, s, 0, 20);

        //encode result
        ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        v.add(new ASN1Integer(r));
        v.add(new ASN1Integer(s));
        return new DERSequence(v).getEncoded(ASN1Encoding.DER);
```

The encoding part seems to be correct, because it works if I produce r and s directly with bouncycastle and another software key. Besides, openssl does accept the input format but the verification fails sometimes with an error, sometimes just with "Verification failure".

Thus, I assume the conversion of the PKCS#11 signature to r and s is wrong. Can someone help finding the mistake?

Comment: The comments were removed, including the one where I asked for a full stack trace. Please provide the full stack trace and preferably some test data and keys.

Comment: Shouldn't the second array copy start at pos 20 instead of 19? Seems like you have the last byte of r twice, and don't ever get the last byte of s.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have to convert the `r` and `s` values to a `BigInteger` class before you do. The reason for this is that ASN.1 uses signed value encoding and DH results in unsigned value encoding. So you've got a pretty high chance of getting a negative value in your ASN.1, which will result in an error.

To perform the conversion, use `new BigInteger(1, r)` and `new BigInteger(1, s)` and put the result into the `ASN1Integer` instances. Here 1 indicates that the value needs to be converted to a positive value (i.e. the input is unsigned positive).

Comment: LuxOnion wrote: "Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to convert r and s to BigInteger. Both, as BigInteger(r) or - as you suggest - BigInteger(1,r) (or, s, respectively). I observe, when parsing the ASN1Sequence with OpenSSL that values are always positive (and I agree, I would expect according to DSA spec that s cannot be negative). However, still the verification fails."